# Entity-relationship (modifying my current digram)

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I'm practicing ERD (entity-relationship diagram); i was trying to solve this particular exercise:

> *We work to build an e-commerce platform that facilitates B2C (business to consumer) and C2C (consumer to consumer) sales. On our
>   platform, anyone who wants to make a sale (be it a company or a
>   person) has a registered user and a catalog of products that they can
>   sell. They can be used or new. For each product that is published for
>   sale, a general definition of parameters is established (the same
>   product may be published more than once with different payment options
>   and / or promotions). Normally, sellers who sell used products have a
>   single unit, while sellers of new products generally handle varied
>   stocks. The available stock of a product can be obtained by being
>   connected to your system (this allows online updating) or manually
>   maintained in our application. Each seller maintains his own product
>   catalog, with the name and details that he considers. Each product is
>   in a category, which makes it easy to search, and can be related to
>   other items (products). We use this a lot for cross selling (for
>   example, someone who buys a battery may be interested in purchasing a
>   charger). In the same purchase I can buy multiple products and / or
>   quantities of each one while they are from the same seller. In case of
>   acquiring multiple items, the seller can pack them together (example
>   if I buy 2 headphones) to simplify and make shipping cheaper or,
>   otherwise, each item will have a different shipping (with a separate
>   cost for each). For each shipment I will have a particular tracking /
>   tracking id (this is done in the supplier of the same, example FedEx).
>   Each purchase has a single shipping address, even if they are divided
>   into multiple packages. A buyer must always be logged in and for each
>   of them we have their personal data, the rating that sellers have
>   given them for their purchases, accumulated points (which give them
>   benefits) and we maintain a history of their operations. With each of
>   the purchases made, our customers add points, which allow them to
>   access many benefits, among which we can mention: Free shipping,
>   discounts on future purchases, etc. The benefits that our buyers have
>   are determined by categories, which are divided by range of points. It
>   should be noted that, in addition, you can also be a seller. Sellers
>   are interested in knowing if it is a company or an individual, their
>   basic tax data (for legal reasons), the rating given by buyers (they
>   are rated between 1 and 5 based on the service and attention
>   provided), how many operations they carried out , what kind of
>   shipments do you make and accepted payment methods. Daily we establish
>   discounts on some publications and they last a few hours. In general
>   they are discounts of between 2% and 10% but they help us to improve
>   sales. This discount does not affect the seller's profit but we absorb
>   it from our company.*

I modeled this diagram, i think it is okay:

[image: r]

The problem is:

> How would you change the exercise (the statement) in order to create
>   another ternary relationship? 
>   Also, what information is relevant if
>   you want to award prizes to buyers for the qualification obtained
>   based on purchases made in the last 3 months and whose amount exceeds
>   500 dollars on average?

Comment: seller and buyer pointing to "type" does not make sense to me.  I'd expect user to point to seller and buyer.  think general to specific just like in OO

Comment: Hey @Hogan , how are you? Thank you for replying!. I'm sorry, i do not completely understand what you're saying: is a hierarchy.

Comment: What do the colors mean?

Comment: Let me put it this way--- is type a relationship?  If it is why is not orange like the other relationships.  If it isn't what is it?

Comment: Green means weak entity
Violet means specialization (hirarchy)
Light blue means enities
orange relationships

Comment: Pink is a ternary relationship

Comment: @Hogan i do not understand how to solve the last part. Can you help me?

Comment: No, I don't understand how you solved the first part